# Issue when broadcasting Taproot transaction to older nodes

Tags: segregated-witness, testnet, taproot, p2tr

I'm trying to broadcast a Taproot transaction to random nodes across the network (Testnet3).

When I try to broadcast to older nodes like 0.18.0, I get the error "Witness version reserved for soft-fork upgrades".

How am I supposed to broadcast a Taproot transaction to older nodes when they won't accept it?

Here is the raw transaction I'm trying to broadcast (it's a very simple single-sig P2TR spend):

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

(Keep in mind it might be broadcasted by the time anyone reads this as newer nodes do accept it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How am I supposed to broadcast a Taproot transaction to older nodes when they won't accept it?

You can't. You need to broadcast it to new nodes for it to propagate.

Comment: Well I guess that solves that. I thought I was going crazy missing something in the documentation. Thanks.